# Liferay developer client webservices

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, liferay

I Followed this [documentation example](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/soap-web-services) (or [this link](http://www.liferay.com/it/web/antonio.junior/blog/-/blogs/consuming-liferay-web-services)) about to create a simple web service client liferay.

Why this code example hase this import:

```
import com.liferay.portal.model.CompanySoap;
import com.liferay.portal.model.UserGroupSoap;
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.CompanyServiceSoap;
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.CompanyServiceSoapServiceLocator; 
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.UserGroupServiceSoap;
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.UserGroupServiceSoapServiceLocator; 
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.UserServiceSoap;
import com.liferay.portal.service.http.UserServiceSoapServiceLocator;
```

(in my example I have compile errros on `UserGroupServiceSoapServiceLocator` (for example) because there is't into `com.liferay.portal`...)

I would have used These import:

```
import com.liferay.client.soap.portal.model.*;
import com.liferay.client.soap.portal.service.*;
import com.liferay.client.soap.portal.service.http.*;
```

When you need to use these imports?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing some issue when I tried to access web services provide by Liferay.
But I can give your answer.
These imports for more than one web service import.
I am using Liferay 6.2 and I am trying too to complete your given link.
http://localhost:8080/api/axis/Portal_CompanyService?wsdl
http://localhost:8080/api/axis/Portal_UserGroupService?wsdl
and for UserServices link is there.
For these three you have to use the same process of web service client stub creation by providing the link.
Thanks